# How to make Windows resolve local hosts by their name?

Tags: dns, hostname

I have a raspberry on my LAN which is recognized as "PI" from my router `Netgear WNDR4300`:

```
Wired Devices:
4   192.168.1.6 B8:27:EB:17:2F:61   PI
```

Unfortunately my Windows doesn't know how to resolve `PI`. I cannot type `ssh pi` on a Cygwin terminal neither do `http://pi:8080` on my browser. I always have to explicitly type the full IP address.

What can I do to allow Windows resolve my raspberry by its name?

Comment: Run `ipconfig` on windows computer and use value of field "Connection-specific DNS Suffix" as suffix for `pi`, so it might be like: `pi.mshome.local`

Comment: Why do you assume your tools are case insensitive?  The router clearly thinks it's "PI" in upper case, but you're using "pi" in lower case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows can resolve names from [multiple sources](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/172218/microsoft-tcp-ip-host-name-resolution-order) (in this order):

1. Own name
2. Hosts file
3. DNS
4. NetBIOS Name Service

This order can be changed in the registry.

So you have the following options:

- Add hosts to your Hosts file manually
- Set up DDNS so the DHCP request host name is used to generate a DNS record – most likely not possible with factory firmware on consumer routers, if it isn’t working out of the box
- Install Samba on your devices and enable at least nmbd

You could also check with `nslookup` whether your router’s DNS server really does not return the correct name. Mine does:

```
> pi     
Server:     192.168.2.1
Address:    192.168.2.1#53

Name:   pi.w23.lan
Address: 192.168.2.15
```

Comment: `apt-get install samba` did the trick. I forgot about `nmbd`

Answer (score 6):

Add the PI and it's IP address to the Hosts file in windows which can be found in **c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts** .

You need to run Notepad or any other text editor As Admin to edit the hosts file.

here is how your hosts file should be:
[image]